# Culture name 'ha-latn' is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual, cultureinfo

I am using Win-8 machine and trying for multilingual web site.

I am using French, Arabic and Hausa language.

My code is working perfect but when I am selecting Hausa language I am getting the error:

> Culture name 'ha-latn' is not supported.

Even I have installed language pack from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/ha-latn-ng/download/details.aspx?id=35403) for this particular language on my machine. Can any body please suggest me how I will solve this problem.

**Update:** I am working under .Net framework 3.5 environment, as this old application and due to some reason I am not updating to newer versions.

Comment: That culture code is correct (although properly the L is capitalised, but that shouldn't matter). "I am getting the error.." is too vague. Be more specific about where and how the error is arising - is it a specific component that does not support that culture? It is an exception? A message being returned by something? How are you "selecting" the language? Ideally, show us some code.

Comment: @JamesWorld the error is occurring at `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ha-Latn");`  line but I changed culture code as "ha-Latn-NG" and the error is gone,got from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) , but it not reflecting any effect my resource file name is "Default.aspx.ha.resx". Application didn't read the values and its still showing me default language.

Comment: Setting the CurrentCulture will affect date/time formatting. If you want to affect resource loading, you need to set CurrentUICulture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution. Hausa language have the culture name "ha-Latn-NG" not "ha-latn".
[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx). Hope it will save someones time.